# Pycharm indentation with HTML (2 spaces) not working correctly how to fix it?

Tags: html, pycharm

I have the pro version of Pycharm.  I am trying to follow a YouTube tutorial to get extra practice and my tabs are working correctly when doing python code just not HTML.  I just want my tabbing to follow the HTML guidelines and auto indent when needed. When ever I hit enter to go to the next line it starts at the very beginning.   I have attached 2 pictures so you can see what I am talking about. Please let me know where I am wrong with my settings.  [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTH6Q.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6nwe.png)

I have went into the settings and have changed a number of different tab settings all with the same result.